# I have attempted to create a trivia game. I am having problems with the output I am looking for

Tags: python

Trying to understand what I am doing wrong here. The output I get when I type in "ohio" or "amsterdam" (or any other variable) is

Votes:

```
Robert: 0
Yukio: 0
Andrew: 1
```

I want the location chosen by the user to give the specified contestant (votesA, votesY, votesR) a point.

```
favorite_places = {
        
    'Andrew': {
        'place1': 'Tokyo', 
        'place2': 'Amsterdam',
        },
        
    'Yukio': { 
        'place1': 'Osaka', 
        'place2': 'Kyoto', 
        },
        
    'Robert': {
        'place1': 'Ohio', 
        'place2': 'Queensland', 
        'place3': 'Auckland',
        }
}


print("Welcome to location quiz poller.\nThese are the contestants choice of favorite places." 
 "Please choose which place is the best, whoever has the most votes will win.")

votesA = 0
votesY = 0
votesR = 0

votinglist = []

for name, place in favorite_places.items():
    #one way to label, access and print nested dictionary values
    places = f"{place['place1']}\n{place['place2']}\n{place.get('place3', '')}\n" 
    print(f"{name}'s favorite places are: ")
    print(f"{places}") 


print("Which place is the best place?")
inp = input('Enter here: ')
inp = inp.lower()

if inp == 'tokyo' or 'amsterdam':
    votesA += 1

elif inp == 'osaka' or 'kyoto':
    votesY += 1

elif inp == 'ohio' or 'queensland' or 'auckland':
    votesR += 1
else:
    print('That is not a valid selection.  -closing program-')

print(f"Votes:\n\tRobert: {votesR}\n\tYukio: {votesY}\n\tAndrew: {votesA}\n\t")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're having problems due to your conditions.

When you say `if inp == 'tokyo' or 'amsterdam':`, you're actually saying in simplified English "if input is Tokyo, or there's a string Amsterdam." That is, you're not actually comparing inp to Amsterdam. "Amsterdam" will always evaluate to `True`, as will any string except empty ones.

What you want is something along the lines of:

```
if inp == 'tokyo' or inp == 'amsterdam':
```

or, even better:

```
if inp in ('tokyo', 'amsterdam'):
```

Comment: Thanks rmssoares. That fixed it perfectly and it makes a lot more sense than what I was doing. You also taught me something new about Python, so thanks again! :)

Comment: No problem! Always happy to help, @faust.